# Using different vendors with the same codebase in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I'm working on a Vue project that is generated with the Vue cli 3. I would like to use different vendors in the same code base.

I need something that can load different images/styling based on a variable. For example something like:

```vue
<!-- In HTML templates -->
<img :src="`@/assets/vendor_name_here/banner.jpg`" />
```

```scss
/* In SCSS */
@import "assets/vendor_name_here/style/bootstrap";
```

Where `vendor_name_here` is a variable that can be set in the environment. Please, note that the above doesn't work.

Coming from an Angular background, something similar could be achieved by simply adding an app or project to the config. However, there is no such thing documented in the Vue docs (of what I could find).

So is there something similar in Vue?

---

#### Update:

I just found out that the following works for HTML images:

```vue
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${VUE_APP_VENDOR}/banner-large.jpg`)" />
```

So the question is still open for the SCSS files.

#### Update 2:

So apparently the same method also works for SCSS files. I added the folowing in my script block:

```js
require(`./assets/${process.env.VUE_APP_VENDOR}/style/bootstrap.scss`);
```

And now it works :).

Answer (score 0):

So I found my own answer to this. The fixes are in the answer itself in the updates.